# ISP Programming pins of ATtiny25 multiplexed for other peripherals

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, schematics, atmel, attiny

We are using [ATtiny25 IC](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2586-avr-8-bit-microcontroller-attiny25-attiny45-attiny85_datasheet.pdf) micro controller interfaced with I2C based Capacitive Sensor [IS31SE5104](http://www.issi.com/WW/pdf/31SE5104.pdf).

[image: Schematics]

ATtiny25(U1) is programmed with (J1) ISP header (SPI pins used), ATtiny I2C pins are multiplexed with ISP pins as per datasheet and same pins planning to use for interfacing IS31SE5104 (U2).

Is it correct approach? Can we use same ATtiny pins for ISP as well as I2C based sensor IS31SE5104?

Please someone guide, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What will be the default state of pins after reset?

Comment: SDA & SCL will be I2C pins, INTB is input pin (default - High) and low when touch detected, SDB is output pin (default-High) and required low for power down mode.

Comment: If I use internal crystal of ATtiny25, can I use XTAL1 and XTAL2 pins for other purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a guide for that from Atmel - [AVR042](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2521-avr-hardware-design-considerations_applicationnote_avr042.pdf). Look especially at section 4.1.1 .

Answer (score 1):

## ISP pins

As Umar already pointed out, you can use them for other purposes

## XTAL1, XTAL2

You can use those also for other purposes if you don't have an external oscillator (see page 60 of the datasheet)